# Clipping from another layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip

I am a Land Surveyor.  I would like to "cut/clip" the tax parcels of a Section.
The amount of data in the file is to great, so I need to "cut/clip" pieces of the file and save them individually so that they can be uploaded to another program.

I have managed to find several Youtube channels for help.
I was even able to "clip" what I described above once and have failed to repeat what I did.

Comment: Some people are not land surveyors :-) Can you describe the nature and format of 
sections and parcels. Have you looked at __ogr2ogr__ (GDAL utility)?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots or drawings to make your question easier to understand?

Comment: You need a layer which covers your area of interest. Input your data layer as the first layer into the clip tool and the layer with your AOI as second. Tada.